# Rebus puzzle for 4th grade

Tags: rebus

I cannot figure this out. I thought it might be raindrops are falling on my head? [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NafIJ.jpg]

Comment: Q: How can a person walk outside in the pouring rain and not have a hair on his head get wet? .........[suspense]................. A: The person is bald.

Comment: Also, welcome to PUZZLING.SE! Check out the rules. If you're wondering, it's not an upside-down person watching hot air balloons fly up.

Comment: Hello @Tiffani and welcome to Puzzling.SE! Be sure to get a tour of this site to earn your first badge and check the [help centre](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help) to guide you in both answering and asking questions. Anyway, happy puzzling :D

Answer (score 2):

Could it be the phrase,

> $\rm Rain \; up \; ahead?$

Because we have

> $\rm Rain + up \, (looks \, up) + a \, head.$

Also,

> the phrase has $11$ letters, as does the amount of raindrops in the picture;

and

> the smile looks like a $\rm \cup$ which is the first letter of "**u**p".

Answer (score 1):

It's probably just a

> Rainhead

Since the picture shows

> A picture of falling water (rain) and a head 
>  Hence, Rain + Head = Rainhead

Although I may be wrong

Comment: $(+1)$ Congrats on $2$,$000$ rep! :D

Answer (score 1):

Could it be...

> Tears of happiness? Teardrops + Happy face

Comment: Or maybe, as I heard the idiom, it could be Rot13(grnef bs wbl). Nice answer! $(+1)$ :D